# Position of composition window of IME in webkit not moved with input focus

Tags: c++, qt, ime, qwebkit

I used a `QWebkit` in my application, when I input some characters into a input control in `QWebkit`, the composition window of IME(Chinese)  is always out of the main window of my application, not displayed at the position of the input control. This problem is not related with specific IME. 
Everything works normally in other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug of QT, I submitted a bug report already.

Comment: What is the Qt bug number or anyway to track it?